# Augmenting `type` from a TypeScript module through declaration files

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to find a solution to extending the definition a of third-party module `next`, by overriding one of the types they have defined.

Looking at a lot of different potential solutions, it seems like this case is different in that `next` exports this particular type, `GetServerSideProps` without any namespace or anything else, which leads me to question whether it's actually possible to change it.

Here's the declaration file I am attempting to augment: [next/types/index.d.ts](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/types/index.d.ts#L156-L161)

I have had some degree of success by declaring the module in a global definition file within my project:

```
declare module "next" {
  type Metadata = import('&/shared/Head').PageMetadata;
  type Props = Partial<Metadata> & {
    [key: string]: import('json-schema').JSONSchema6Type;
  };

  export type GetServerSideProps<
    P extends Props = Props,
    Q extends import('querystring').ParsedUrlQuery = import('querystring').ParsedUrlQuery
  > = (
    context: import('next').GetServerSidePropsContext<Q>
  ) => Promise<import('next').GetServerSidePropsResult<P>>
}
```

However, the consequence of this is that the entire module declaration from `next` is just that. It's not extending from the existing declaration.

Another problem is that the `GetServerSidePropsContext` and `GetServerSidePropsResult` fails to import from the original `next` declaration. I can see that this is because TS now resolves `next` to this module declaration, so that all makes sense. This problem is secondary, in that I want to resolve whether it's actually possible to augment the module like this.

Hope someone is able to give some pointers, appreciated :)

Comment: Shouldn't you import the module first? As far as I know, you can simply `import "module";` and then proceed with module augmentation

Comment: @OlegValter As soon as I add an import statement like that, TypeScript doesn't recognize the file. My understanding is that this happens because it turns it into a "local" declaration file, instead of "global".

Comment: Well, yeah, it becomes a module - don't think you can both augment a module without shadowing it *and* keep a file as a global declaration file. I'd suggest moving the module augmentation part to its own file - should work fine.

Comment: @OlegValter If I move it to another file, it would not import with other imports from the `next` module, right? Have I missed out on a solution here?

Comment: it should - the imports from the `next` module should start to see the augmentations alongside the "native" exports. I am not sure about your setup, but sure seems to be ok in a setup quickly thrown together.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right. After more fiddling around, it seems like the conclusion is simply that I cannot override a `type` export, and my example above is fully functional, but simply ignored. Thank you for your help, Oleg!

Comment: Hm, I missed that you are overriding an already defined type alias, sorry. You may find [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28078) interesting then (although hardly any solace since the answer is basically "no") Re: help - NP!